# How to correctly echo Notify.js notification using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to echo Notify.js notification script after the PHP code has been executed, however, it is not working for some reason.

```
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
        echo alert('Sorry, something went wrong.');
        exit();   
    }else{
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $cat_name);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php?add_category','_self')</script>";
        // notify.js notification
        echo '<script>$.notify("Notification text...", "success");</script>';
}
```

As you can see in the code, after the statement has been executed, the page reloads and thats the moment when I want to get the notification. Could someone tell me please, me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If your question has been answered then accepting an answer with the check mark can help others find an answer as well as in directing community effort. If your question has not been answered, please drop a comment to request additional information or update your question to include a more specific request.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to perform an action after the page is lost.

When you run `window.open` with `_self` as the target, you can fairly safely assume that no other JS on the current page will run.

What you will want instead, is checking on the `index.php` page for the `add_category` `$_POST` key, and trigger your notification at that time.